# total mass of lamina and center of mass

Tags: integration

A lamina occupies the part of the rectangle [image] , $ \ 0 \le y \le 2 \ $ , and the density at each point is given by the function [image]

What is the total mass?

Where is the center of mass?

My problem is setting the integral!

Comment: What are the bounds on the rectangle in the $ \ y-$ direction?

Comment: is it from 0 to 7?!

Comment: I don't know:  you only gave the interval for $ \ x \ $ .

Comment: oh Y is from 0 to 2

Comment: Omg :D This is the first time I've recognized where to use a double integral.

Comment: When the density function is not constant and has no simple symmetry with respect to the shape of the figure, you really have little choice.

Comment: This maybe helpful : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricCentroid.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mass of a rectangular lamina with boundaries $ \ a \le x \le b \ $ and $ \ c \le y \le d \ $ is given by

$$ M \ = \ \int_c^d \ \int_a^b \ \ \rho (x,y) \ \ dx \ dy \ . $$

The coordinates of the centroid ("center-of-mass" in physical applications) are found from

$$ \overline{x} \ = \ \frac{\int_c^d \ \int_a^b \ \ x \cdot \rho (x,y) \ \ dx \ dy}{M} \ \ , $$

$$ \overline{y} \ = \ \frac{\int_c^d \ \int_a^b \ \ y \cdot \rho (x,y) \ \ dx \ dy}{M} \ \ . $$

Note that since the density gets larger as we go toward the "upper-right" corner, $ \ (7,2) \ , $ we should expect the centroid to be "above and to the right" of the center of the rectangle at $ \ ( \frac{7}{2} , 1 ) \ . $
[Later, I'll mention a handy way to get the mass without integration when the density function is linear in each dimension...]

For the sake of guidance, I get $ \ M \ = \ 273 \ , \ \overline{x} \ = \ \frac{1127}{273} \ , \ \overline{y} \ = \ \frac{875}{3 \ \cdot \ 273} \ . $ (No one said the centroid coordinates would be pretty -- just rational...)

**EDIT:** The "short-cut" I was holding off mentioning is that when linear functions are involved, some calculations can be greatly simplified because of the way some integrals work.  The density function in this problem, $ \ \rho(x, y) = 3x + 4y + 5 \ $ , is linear in both the $ \ x-$ and $ \ y-$ directions.  In this situation, the mass of the lamina is just the density at the geometrical center of the region (*not* the centroid; the two only coincide for *uniform* density) times the area.  For this problem, we thus find

$$ M \ = \ A \ \cdot \ \rho(x_m, y_m) \ = \ (b-a) \ (d-c) \cdot \ \rho(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{c+d}{2})  $$

$$ = \ 7 \ \cdot \ 2 \ \cdot \ \rho(\frac{7}{2},1) \ = \ 14 \ \cdot (3 \cdot \frac{7}{2} \  + \ 4 \cdot 1 \ + \ 5) \ = \ 14 \ \cdot \ 19.5 \ = \ 273\ \ . $$

Comment: $\frac{1127}{273}=\frac{161}{39},\ \frac{875}{273}=\frac{125}{39}$